# Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Say a shortcode to do this. As image

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
future image
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<h2>Post title</h2>
<p>post<p>
<a herf="link">more</a>
</div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6mrI.png)

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, and it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself.  Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking, how to make a shortcode that outputs the above code, then you do something like this:

```
function myshortcode_example() 
{
    ob_start();
    ?>
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-md-4">
future image
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<h2>Post title</h2>
<p>post<p>
<a herf="link">more</a>
</div>
</div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'myshortcode_example' );
```